# Does mv use an alias by default?

Tags: command-line, alias, mv

In the context of shell, much as `cp`, `rm` use an alias that prompts to overwrite, does `rm` use an alias also?

This is usually bypassed by using `\cp` and `\rm` for example.  Does the same also apply to `mv`?

Comment: Depends on how you set up your shell environment! Do you mean which Linux distributions make an alias for `mv` by default?

Comment: Yes; I happen to use Centos 7, but if you can answer the question in general terms and address the distributions...

Comment: It's not *my* question, it's your question. What do you want to know? How *I* have my shell set up, or??

Answer (score 2):

If you type `alias` into your terminal, you will see all current aliases.

Comment: I find `type -a some_command` to be very instructive.